# Can 's be used to mean was?

Tags: contractions, copular-verbs

Can *'s* be used as a contraction of *was*?

For example, can "maybe **she's born** that way" mean "maybe **she was born** that way"?

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. Please [edit] your question to remove the text that isn't related to what you're asking.

Comment: This post is a mess. Please fix it or it will be closed.

Comment: And please add text that explains what you're asking.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is probably "no". "She's"  would almost always be interpreted as "she is".